# ViewDidLoad not setting correct button state

Tags: ios, objective-c

I changed my segmented control because with the new phone sizes and iOS 8, it was cutting off my first segment, Changed to fixed and 38 to 39 on the width. Now my initial button state are not setting. Specifically my start button is not initializing to YES.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Updates time on currentTimeLabel
    [self updateTime];

    // Sets initial button states
    [self setInitialState];

    // Sets UITextField delegate
    self.startLevel.delegate = self;
    self.stopLevel.delegate = self;

     // initializes basic values for tank control
    bigTank = YES;
    tankResource = @"dragonBarrelChart";
    [self.tankControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Tank Calculator view did load.");

}
```

I am totally stunned. Makes no sense whatsoever. Upon hitting a manual reset using a button, all buttons reset as desired.

Here is the setInitialState code triggered by both the button and on viewDidLoad. Should work identically...

```
// Sets initial button and label states
- (void)setInitialState
 {
    self.start.enabled = YES;
    self.stop.enabled = NO;
    self.calculate.enabled = NO;
    self.resume.enabled = NO;

    // Text for time labels reset
    _startTimeLabel.text = @"- -:- -:- -.- -";
    _stopTimeLabel.text = @"- -:- -:- -.- -";

    // Resets the minuteRateLabel
    _minuteRateLabel.text = @"--.--";

    // Resets the text fields to their initial state with the placeholder "inches" text
    [_startLevel setText:nil];
    [_stopLevel setText:nil];

    // Resets inch levels to EVEN
    [self.startFractionControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    [self.stopFractionControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    startFractions = @"";
    stopFractions = @"";

}
```

What am I doing wrong??? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How are you determining that the start button is not initiating to YES (I assume you mean its enabled state)?

Comment: Because it it not enabling to yes on launch in simulator.

Comment: I'm asking how do you know that. Does it just not respond to touches, or is it also grayed out?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you set delegates with `self.startLevel.delegate = self;` and `self.stopLevel.delegate = self;` but do you set your segmented control delegate as well?

Comment: setInitialState includes the start button state. It is hit in viewDidLoad. How would this make a difference? nitial button states
    [self setInitialState];